# How to convert Liquid array to a Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, jekyll, liquid

In my Jekyll site, I want to load data from `_data/stocks.yml` and use the data in a Chart.js-powered graph. Chart.js accepts chart datasets and labels as simple Javascript arrays. Is there an easy way to convert a Liquid array to a Javascript array or map?

I tried doing: `var months = {{ site.data.stocks.yml | json }}` but I think that only works for individual strings/variables and not collection structures.

The `_data/stocks.yml` file:

```
- month: Jan '20
  portfolio: '-4.5'
  spy: '-0.16'
- month: Feb '20
  portfolio: '-19.2'
  spy: '-8.41'
- month: Mar '20
  portfolio: '-19.1'
  spy: '-12.51'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are two issues with what you're trying to accomplish.

The first is that that, according to the [jekyll documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/#example-list-of-members), you should access a data file using the format `site.data.datafile` without the extension `.yml`. In your case, you would access your data using `{{ site.data.stocks }}`

The second is that the jekyll (liquid) filter for converting to json is `| jsonify`, not `| json`. So to convert your stocks data file to json you would use `{{ site.data.stocks | jsonify }}`

Comment: That’s brilliant thank you! I found the `json` filter on the Liquid developer page. Clearly I did not dig deep enough on the Jekyll documentation page.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a liquid array, then I think the simple way would be looping through the liquid array and pushing elements into the JS array on each iteration.

E.g.:

```
<script>
let js_array =[];
  {% for item in liquid_array %}
     js_array.push({{item}});
  {% endfor %}
console.log(js_array);
</script>
```